# Pause Wait Feature in Dial Application

Tags: android, android-intent

I have made a small application that dials a number.

After dialling I wait for the automated answering machine to end its message using ';' character that I have put in the dial string.

After that again I need to enter another string which would be an entry key "123456#" I again intend to wait for the automated answering machine to end its message.

Then dial "0000#"

The probelm I am facing is The last string "0000#" does not appear in the called number display and hence not dialed. I also tried with giving ',''s within the string but it does not work.

What can be the problem.

```
protected void makeCall() {
      Log.i("Make call", "");
      EditText pnum = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Primary_number);
      EditText pwd = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Key);
      Intent phoneIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
      //phoneIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+pnum.getText() + ";"+pwd.getText()));
      phoneIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:36020198;123456789#;0000#"));

      try {
         startActivity(phoneIntent);
         finish();
         Log.i("Finished making a call...", "");
      } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, 
         "Call faild, please try again later.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the string

```
phoneIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:36020198;123456789#;0000#"));
```

add the pound symbol using this:

```
phoneIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:36020198;123456789"+"%23"+";0000"+"%23"));
```